# FileNotFoundException - Struts2 File Upload

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

Strange `FileNotFoundException` while uploading file using Struts2. This is a part of JSP:

```
<a:form action="/FileUploadServletAction.action" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<a:file name="fileUpload" label="File"/>
<a:submit/>
```

This is the execute() method, to copy uploaded file from temporary location to actual location:

```
public String execute() throws Exception{
try {
        String filePath = "c:/foo";
        System.out.println("Server path:" + filePath);
        File fileToCreate = new File(filePath, this.fileUploadContentType);
        FileUtils.copyFile(this.fileUpload, fileToCreate);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        addActionError(e.getMessage());
        return INPUT;
    }

    return SUCCESS;
}
```

This is my portion of struts.xml which configures above Action class:

```
<action name="FileUploadServletAction"
        class="com.test.FileUploadServletAction">
        <result name="input">/jsp/upload.jsp</result>
        <result name="success">/jsp/upload.jsp</result>
        <result name="error">/jsp/error.jsp</result>
</action>
```

But when I run I get this exception:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: Source 'E:\Foo\Projects\Foo\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\work\Catalina\localhost\FooProject\upload_1ec6cc50_75d7_482f_83be_fe4185999973_00000000.tmp' does not exist
at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyFile(FileUtils.java:1074)
at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyFile(FileUtils.java:1038)

INFO: Removing file fileUpload E:\Foo\Projects\Foo\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\work\Catalina\localhost\FooProject\upload_1ec6cc50_75d7_482f_83be_fe4185999973_00000000.tmp
```

Can anyone let me know why Struts is not able to find temporary file which is created? Please let me know if you need additional information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are missing getter and setter methods, I don't know have you defined or not?

**JSP code:**

```
<form action="FileUploadServletAction" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <label>File:</label><input type="file" name="userKey"/>
  <input type="image" src="images/login-btn.jpg" alt="submit" width="103" height="42"/>
</form>
```

**Action code:**

```
//In FileUploadServletAction
private File userKey;  //file name which is on JSP
private String userKeyContentType;
private String userKeyFileName;  

//getter, setter  
public File getUserKey() 
{
    return userKey;
}

public void setUserKey(File userKey) 
{
    this.userKey = userKey;
}

public String getUserKeyFileName()
{
    return userKeyFileName;
} 

public String getUserKeyContentType() 
{
    return userKeyContentType;
}

public void setUserKeyContentType(String userKeyContentType)
{
    this.userKeyContentType = userKeyContentType;
}

public void setUserKeyFileName(String userKeyFileName)
{
    this.userKeyFileName = userKeyFileName;
}
```

Now, `execute()` method

```
//In FileUploadServletAction
public String execute() throws Exception{
 try {
      String filePath = request.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("/");           
      File fileToCreate = new File(filePath, this.userKeyFileName);
      FileUtils.copyFile(this.userKey, fileToCreate);
  } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    addActionError(e.getMessage());
    return INPUT;
 }

 return SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Hi @Aniket, yes I have defined getter/setter for all of the fields.

Comment: @PradeepSimha : Can you try my code? I had same requirement, I edited my code according to your post. It was working for me.

Answer (score 1):

try with inteceptor
your action should like this..

```
 <action name="FileUploadServletAction"  class="com.test.FileUploadServletAction">
            <interceptor-ref name="fileUpload">
                <param name="maximunSize">1024000</param>
                <param name="allowedTypes">
                     your types
                </param>
            </interceptor-ref>
            <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"></interceptor-ref>
            <result name="input">/jsp/upload.jsp</result>
            <result name="success">/jsp/upload.jsp</result>
            <result name="error">/jsp/error.jsp</result>
    </action>
```

Comment: I have already configured this for a simplicity sake I didn't mentioned in my post. But still I am getting same exception.

Comment: try this **String path = httpServletRequest.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("/");**. create a HttpServletRequest object and it's getter, setter. it's the reason the file not found. If you want your custom path, tell in web.xml

Comment: Added, but still same issue.

Comment: Link to my action class: http://codeviewer.org/view/code:38d7, web.xml: http://codeviewer.org/view/code:38d8, struts.xml: http://codeviewer.org/view/code:38d9. Because I cannot post full files here.

Comment: Yes, I am getting correct object in fileUpload. It's displaying path to temp file.