# How can i implement upload file in struts2 with hibernate

Tags: mysql, hibernate, file-upload, struts2, upload

I m developping a web app ( Electronic Document Managemen) and i need file upload in strurts 2 and store it to mysql using hibernate, can anybody give better idea. advance thanks

```
Post edited :
```

I have  start with this :
 in pojo class  i have:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Documents")
public class Documents {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="idDocument")
    private Integer idDocument;

    @Column(name="content")
    @Lob
    private byte[] content;

    @Column(name="description")
    private String description;
```

in class  documentsDaoimpl  i have :

```
 public class DocumentsDaoImpl implements DocumentsDao{
    @SessionTarget
    Session session;

    @TransactionTarget
    Transaction transaction;

    @Override
    public void saveOrUpdateDocuments(Documents Document) {
        try {

            session.saveOrUpdate(Document);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            transaction.rollback();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }       
    } .......
```

In action class i have :

```
public class DocumentAction  extends ActionSupport implements ModelDriven<Documents>{
    private Documents document=new Documents();
    private DocumentsDao documentdao=new DocumentsDaoImpl();

    @Override
    public Documents getModel() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return document;
    }
    public String saveOrUpdate(){   
        documentdao.saveOrUpdateDocuments(document);
            list();
            return SUCCESS;
        }
.......
```

And the JSP i have a form :

```
<s:form action="saveOrUpdateDocuments" method="post">
    <s:hidden name="document.idDocument" />
    <s:textfield name="document.description" label="document File "  required="true" />
    <s:file  name="document.content"  value="Add Document"/>
     <s:submit value="upload"  />
</s:form>
```

I don't Know how can i progressed

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19925555/1031945

Answer (score 0):

Are you planning to store files in database as blob type? Declare your column as `BLOB` type in database and in your model class declare a variable of type `byte[]`.

```
//userFile is the file submitted from JSP
byte[] bFile = new byte[(int) userFile.length()];
try {
         FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(userFile);
         //convert file into array of bytes
         fileInputStream.read(bFile);
         fileInputStream.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Now, you can save the `bFile` into your database. Code taken from [this tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-save-image-into-database/).

If you simply want to save your image on disk you can follow [this code](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/struts-2-file-upload-save-tutorial-with-example/). It also shows how to submit file from JSP using struts 2 form.

Comment: thanks for your response , Yes I want store files in database as blob type but i d't know how , I have edite my post can   you  look it for give me recommandation

Comment: showing your struts.xml would have been helpful. Follow the [second tutorial](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/struts-2-file-upload-save-tutorial-with-example/) given in the answer. Declare form element `userImage`,`userImageContentType` etc like that. Also update your action class according to that tutorial. Then make sure you are able to get the files submitted in your action class. When you are able to do that then start changing it according to your specific requirements. Let me know if you face any further problems. Also I noticed a typo `@Lob`